# how to add column with number of occurrences by two fields

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1,5,2,2,2,5],'c2':[2,2,2,2,1,2]})

   c1  c2
0   1   2
1   5   2
2   2   2
3   2   2
4   2   1
5   5   2
```

I try to get

```
   c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   1
1   5   2   2
2   2   2   2
3   2   2   2
4   2   1   1
5   5   2   2
```

I started with

```
df['c3'] = df.groupby('c1')['c2'].transform('size')
```

but don't know how to groupy by two columns.

Comment: Actually, your output isn't clear to me. It can be achieved like I did, by just counting the occurrence of values greater than 1 across rows. Beyond that, I don't see a pattern.

Comment: 1 2 appears once
5 2 appears twice
2 2 appears twice
2 1 appears once

Answer (score 1):

if you need just count using group by then you can try like below

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1,5,2,2,2,5],'c2':[2,2,2,2,1,2]})

print (df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).size().reset_index(name='counts'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `list.count`:

```
l = df.values.tolist()
df['c3'] = [l.count(i) for i in l]
```

Output:

```
   c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   1
1   5   2   2
2   2   2   2
3   2   2   2
4   2   1   1
5   5   2   2
```